# Make a generic/parametrize trigger in azure data factory

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-factory, data-pipeline

I want to load data from on premise to azure blobs. I have data on three on premise servers. Problem is that data copying should run at different time for each source.
Please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle this would be three Triggers, each set one time and target.